# How to show livewire component as modal window for filament table action

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire, filamentphp

I am going to show a livewire component in modal window when user clicks a filament table action.

```
    protected function getTableActions()
    {
        return [
            ActionGroup::make([
                ViewAction::make()->form([
                    TextInput::make('name'),
                    TextInput::make('email'),
                ]),
                DeleteAction::make(),
                ForceDeleteAction::make(),
                RestoreAction::make(),
                Action::make('assign')
                    ->icon('heroicon-o-trash')
            ])
        ];
    }
```

When clicked assign button, I want to show a modal window and the use a livewire component as modal window content.
I tried to find the solution and looked around filament table actin docs, but I couldn't find.
Please help me to find what functions to call for making custom filament table action for showing a livewire component in modal window.

I tried to call like this but this is the only view. I want to use a full livewire component.

```
    protected function getTableActions()
    {
        return [
            ActionGroup::make([
                ViewAction::make()->form([
                    TextInput::make('name'),
                    TextInput::make('email'),
                ]),
                DeleteAction::make(),
                ForceDeleteAction::make(),
                RestoreAction::make(),
                Action::make('assign')
                    ->icon('heroicon-o-trash')
                    ->action(fn () => $this->record->advance())
                    ->modalFooter(view('livewire.assign-course'))
            ])
        ];
    }
```

Comment: @javierstere could you explain what is the purpose of the livewire component which you want to show in the modal? you may want to keep using filament actions tools to achieve it instead of building a custom livewire component on top of that modal. if you want to customize what is shown in the modal, this can help https://filamentphp.com/docs/3.x/actions/modals#custom-modal-content